# Access constructor variables inside the render method - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple registration form as shown in the below code and is aiming to do display my validation message on submit. The code is mostly in react and pure js.

```
import React from 'react';

class Register extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleSubmit  = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.validationMsg = [];
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let target   = event.target;

        for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

            let item = target.elements[i];
            let name = item.getAttribute("name")
            let msg  = name + ' is required.'

            if (item.value === '') {
                this.validationMsg.push({
                    [name]: msg
                });
            }
        }
        console.log('validationMsg', this.validationMsg);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="username" />
                {this.validationMsg.username}
                <input type="text" name="email" />
                {this.validationMsg.email}
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

My question is how can i access `this.validationMsg` declared inside the constructor from the
`render` Method.

Basically what am saying is that my `{this.validationMsg.username}` or `{this.validationMsg.email}` is not working, meaning its does not display anything nor any error is thrown.

However when i click submit i can view my desired result inside the `handleSubmit` Function at

```
console.log('validationMsg', this.validationMsg);
```

How can i show the values from this.validationMsg inside the render() Method?

Comment: `this.validationMsg` is a list.

Comment: Well, take note any change in `validationMsg` doesn't cause a re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error messages are actually stored in a `normal variable` of your class. So, the component **will not render** to show the error message. You should store it in the component `state`. You can find more details about how react components handle the data changes [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Here is the update code which uses state. And the working [codepen](https://codepen.io/jamesweb/pen/rNNOQRQ).

```
class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleSubmit  = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          validationMsg: {}
        };
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let target = event.target;
        const validationMsg = {};

        for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

            let item = target.elements[i];
            let name = item.getAttribute("name")
            let msg  = name + ' is required.'

            if (item.value === '') {
              validationMsg[name] = msg;
            }
        }
        this.setState({ validationMsg });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="username" />
                {this.state.validationMsg.username}
                <input type="text" name="email" />
                {this.state.validationMsg.email}
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `validationMsg` to object

```
import React from 'react';

class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleSubmit  = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.validationMsg = {};
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let target = event.target;

        for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

            let item = target.elements[i];
            let name = item.getAttribute("name")
            let msg  = name + ' is required.'

            if (item.value === '') {
                this.validationMsg[name] = msg;
            }
        }
        console.log('validationMsg', this.validationMsg);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="username" />
                {this.validationMsg.username}
                <input type="text" name="email" />
                {this.validationMsg.email}
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.validationMsg` is a list, so you should be change to `this.validationMsg = {}`.

Add key value into an object:

```
if (item.value === '') {
    this.validationMsg[name] = msg
}
```

**But**, in your case, you should use `this.state` to manage error like this:

```
this.state = {
   validationMsg: {}
}

if (item.value === '') {
   const validationMsgTmp = ...this.state.validationMsg; 
   // Create a deep clone this.state
   this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      validationMsg: validationMsgTmp[name] = msg 
      // Add key: value into object state
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `state` for this. You can find a detailed docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

In reactjs the state of a class holds everything. If you update the `state`. The render function is recalled with the updated value.

To do that you should use `setState`. I have made some changes in your code to explain this.

```
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleSubmit  = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        validationMsg = []
    }
}
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //Changes here
    let validation = [];

    let target   = event.target;

    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

        let item = target.elements[i];
        let name = item.getAttribute("name")
        let msg  = name + ' is required.'

        if (item.value === '') {
            validation.push({
                [name]: msg
            });
        }
    }
    console.log('validationMsg', this.validationMsg);
    this.setState({validationMsg: validation})
}
```

Your render function should be like this:

```
return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        {this.state.validationMsg.username}
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        {this.state.validationMsg.email}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
    </form>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `this.validationMsg` as array and then try to access it as an individual object. You could look into using `map` instead:

```
return (
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    {this.validationMsg.map(message => message.username)}
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    {this.validationMsg.map(message => message.email)}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
  </form>
);
```

Generally it is better to save this kind of data to the state, since you use it for rendering:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      validationMsg: []
    }
  }

 handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let target = event.target;
  const message = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

    let item = target.elements[i];
    let name = item.getAttribute("name")
    let msg = name + ' is required.'

    if (item.value === '') {
      message.push({
        [name]: msg
      });
    }

  }

  this.setState({
    validationMsg: message
  });
}


// then in render
const {validationMsg} = this.state; 

return (
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    {validationMsg.map(message => message.username)}
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    {validationMsg.map(message => message.email)}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SIGN UP" />
  </form>
);
```